# Is there an aws cli call that I can use that does not require authentication?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I have a Terraform module that is used to get information from AWS that is not available within Terraform. The module is open source and is in the Terraform Registry and seems to be popular with over 2.7K provisions.

I am now wanting to add some unit tests to the package.

Locally, my tests all work fine as I have AWS credentials.

What I'd like to do is make ANY call to AWS using the AWS CLI that can return JSON output, but does not require any credentials.

I was hoping for something like a list of AWS Regions, or AWS products, but all require credentials.

The tests are not about specific values but purely about the communication, data retrieval, and processing. Not about the content (as such).

So. Really. ANY output as long as it is JSON.

Alternatively, are there any sort of "test" credentials that are allowed to be used for this sort of thing. As these credentials have to be present in the pipeline, they need to be ones that have no capability of being misused.

Answer (score 2):

A popular choice to mock AWS services is through [localstack](https://github.com/localstack/localstack). You could deploy it and use locally for your tests without the need for any real AWS credentials.

With regard to calls to AWS services, AWS CLI supports [--no-sign-request](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/). This does not require any credentials, but has **very limited use**. Basically its only good for accessing public S3 buckets. Since they are public, there is no need to use AWS credentials to access them.

Answer (score 0):

With massive thanks to @Marcin's answer, here is the command I am using.

```
aws s3api list-objects --bucket ryft-public-sample-data --no-sign-request --output json --query 'max_by(Contents, &Size)'
```

This allows me to validate that my module is operating as expected and that it integrates with Terraform. And I can put the tests public as it does not require any credentials.

Thank you.